# Embedded AngularJS App and RequireJS/AMD error

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, requirejs, single-page-application

I have an AngularJS application, which is used inside an existing website.

something like this:

```
<div ng-app="configurator" ng-controller="SomeController as someController" data-auth="some-jwt-token" class="app-wrapp">...</div>
```

The website is using requireJS for their JavaScript stuff. And this is where my app breaks with following error:

```
mnty.1464947369.js:65 Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function (){return factory()}
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatchmakeError @ mnty.1464947369.js:65v @ mnty.1464947369.js:65o @ mnty.1464947369.js:65requirejs @ mnty.1464947369.js:65(anonymous function) @ mnty.1464947369.js:70fetchPlugins @ mnty.1464947369.js:70process @ mnty.1464947369.js:70mount @ mnty.1464947369.js:70(anonymous function) @ main_3-21-6.js:149u @ mnty.1464947369.js:66fireWith @ mnty.1464947369.js:66ready @ mnty.1464947369.js:66a @ mnty.1464947369.js:65
app-bundled.js:6 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module configurator due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module rzModule due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'rzModule' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/$injector/nomod?p0=rzModule
```

Some of used modules use UMD in their build, but most not. This is the key problem I think. How can I solve this issue?

(the AngularJS app ist bundled in a single JS-file and is included in footer of the page)

Comment: Will you please show us code of your configuration js file ??

Comment: This question is very poorly written. There are multiple errors caused by different problems. I've closed against a question which deals with your first error message ("Mismatched anonymous define") take care of that, include a [mcve] in your question, and then we can reopen. Right now, the lack of MCVE has caused you to get 3 answers that did not fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the load order of your modules, as you can see here:

```
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'rzModule' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it.
```

Check that this module is getting loaded into angular before you load `configurator` module.

Comment: The module contains UMD, so it is using requireJS and not the global angularJS loader, therefore angularjs don't know about it. And this is my problem.

Comment: Hm, I see, then can you require rzModule just before creating your module? 
Also, can you share the repo or where does this rzModule come from?

Answer (score 0):

you are using `ng-app="configurator"` and the error showing

```
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'rzModule' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it.
```

So module name should be same.

Comment: rzModule is a dependency of configurator

Answer (score -1):

I have to agree with 6uitar6reat6od and Durgpal Singh, you might also have a JS file with a `define` method which conflicts with require js, to solve this you need to properly configure this file within your require configuration section